# JavaScript closure and jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have html code as below:

```
<div class='items'>
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='text1'>...</div>
        <div class='text2'>...</div>
        <img src='...'/>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='text1'>...</div>
        <div class='text2'>...</div>
        <img src='...'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for each div with 'item' class I want to get height of divs '.text1' and '.text2' to vertically align content. So i wrote a JS code as below:

```
var items = $('.items .item');
var item;
var img;
var diff;
var slideHeight;
var contentHeight = 0;

items.each(function() {
    item = $(this);

    function(i) {
        img = i.find('img');

        img.load(function() {
            contentHeight = 0;
            slideHeight = i.height();

            contentHeight += i.find('.text1').height();
            contentHeight += i.find('.text2').height();

            console.log(i.find('.text1').html());
            console.log(i.find('.text2').html());

            diff = slideHeight - contentHeight;

            console.log(slideHeight, contentHeight, diff);
        });
    })(item);
});
```

In console I got:
533 61 472 - it looks quite reliably
and..
533 0 533 - and here is the problem

It's confusing because lines:

```
console.log(i.find('.text1').html());
console.log(i.find('.text2').html());
```

prints valid content form divs. Should I create another closure and put in therein load() function? - I tried. Result was same.

Comment: check with .innerHeight()

Comment: No difference, same behaviour

Comment: you should check this when page load .. load() function with .innerHeight()

Comment: @Mariusz Jucha, can you please post your full js code.

Comment: And that's what I'm doing. JS code above is one of many functions from (function() { ... });